# Input values are not reflected on view model after changing via javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm currently working on ASP.Net MVC application and I use a ViewModel to pass data to post `HttpPost` action as:

```
@model Project.Lib.ViewModels.Campaigns.CampaignViewModel

<form asp-controller="Campaigns" asp-action="Create" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="needs-validation" role="form" novalidate>
    <input asp-for="NumberOfWeeks" class="form-control" id="weeks" disabled>
   ...
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1" value="Save Campaign"/>

</form>
```

So as you can see, I have one input

And I calculate the input assigning the value via javascript as:

```
function checkDates () {
         const startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value
         const endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value

         document.getElementById('weeks').value = weeksBetween(new Date(startDate),  new Date(endDate))
         }
```

This input showed the correct value.

[image]

The problem is when I do the post that, the inputs comes null as below picture

[image]

Comment: When you submit a form the whole page is refreshed.

Comment: Yes @PoulBak on controller I have a simple  `return View(model);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is when I do the post that, the inputs comes null as below
> picture

Because   you use `disabled`, so the inputs of `NumberOfWeeks` comes null. If you  want the `NumberOfWeeks` field cannot be modified, you can use `readonly` like this:

```
<input asp-for="NumberOfWeeks" class="form-control" id="weeks" readonly>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: @Jesus   Disabled `<input>` elements in a form will not be submitted. Have a look at [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled), we can see " The Boolean disabled attribute, when present, makes the element not mutable, focusable, or even submitted with the form. "